# JDeveloper 10g Web service get XML SOAP response request?

Tags: java, web-services, jdeveloper, oc4j, jax-rpc

Is there a way to capture the XML requests / responses for a JDeveloper 10g OC4J Web service which is using JAX-RPC?

We would like to store the XMLs into our database.

Comment: Did you find any thing useful ?

Comment: Not really, I found that you can add an option within the web service to log the xml in the OC4J logs, but not how to capture the XML itself in code.

Comment: Could you tell me what is this option. Any reference will be helpfull

Comment: From within the Enterprise Manager, go to your application, then click on the Web Services tab, select the port (hyperlink). Then click Administration tab, from here you can enable Auditing and Tracing of the messages.